# How to query current user created items?

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, column, caml-query

I have many lists in SharePoint site. I want to retreive all the items from the list and display on a site. The current user should only see his/her created items not other users items from the lists. Is my query right or can you help me to get the proper one please?

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); 
var textCAML = '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author'/></Eq></Where></Query></View>';
camlQuery.set_viewXml(textCAML);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would look like this (from memory):

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); 
var textCAML = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID/></Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
camlQuery.set_viewXml(textCAML);
```